# How to integrate Mercurial with PHPed IDE?

Tags: php, mercurial, settings, integration, phped

Can anyone post the steps for integrating mercurial to phped.

I followed the following steps, listed by one member on their forum:

What to do: Creating a Commit Shortcut
    * Install Mercurial if you have not already. I've installed mine to c:\development\Mercurial\
    * Go to PHPEd Settings > Tools > Integration
    * Create a new menu called "Hg" (or Mercurial or whatever you want to call it)
    * Create a new Sub Menu called "Hg Commit"
    * Edit "Hg Commit" with the following settings:

```
      o Execute with "Shell"
      o Command line: D:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe commit @Name@ --cwd @Path@
      o Check off "Show this command in File Bar popup" (optional)
      o Shortcut: CTL-SHIFT-M (or anything you like)
      o Check off Redirect Error stream to Log Window and Redirect Output to Window
```

But when i commit, i get the following error:

> - Script D:\Program    Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe commit createXML.php --cwd D:\xampp\htdocs\XML\
> - Script Failed    to run command "D:\Program", error    code: 2, system
>     description: "The    system cannot
>     find the file    specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotation marks around the path to hg.exe. The space in Program Files is throwing it off and it's only looking for something in D:\Program, which probably doesn't even exist.

Note that I've never used PHPed, so there might be more problems. But that is the one producing the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Presently, the above settings opens up Notepad to write down the Commit message. Is there a way to open Notepad++ or TortoiseHg own Commit Window ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question, sorry.

Comment: @Ibn no questions in comments, please. just ask another question; we don't bite.

Comment: it was related so i thought i could ask. Sorry about that.